# I have two internet connections, how to automatically switch when one internet fails?

Tags: networking, internet, 21.04

I have Ubuntu 21. I am from India, and have two Fiber Internet connections via Lan cable.

The internet here are not reliable. Every day, one internet connection stops working for 2-3 minutes or so randomly. I wanted to know, when one internet don't work, how can I automatically switch internet?

I am going outside, and need to access my computer via teamviewer 24/7. So a reliable connection is needed. I am new to ubuntu, please consider me a newbie.

Comment: What you mean exactly by "Fails" and "stops working".

Comment: I can't open websites. Can't receive or send data over the internet. All lights are green on the modem. Internet is connected, but no internet.

Comment: Same as, what happens, when you don't recharge your internet. If that makes it clear. Thanks sir @Marco

Comment: someone told me, I need to buy Load balancer device from TP Link. WIll that make my internet more reliable?

Comment: Use Netplan. See https://netplan.io/examples/, and also check their reference and design pages.

Comment: How should any system detect "lights are green" ? To detect "not receiving data from webpage" can only be detected with a timeout and how long should this be? And how to distinguish between your internet problem and the webpage problem? I assume a most devices will only detect "link down".

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu has products that use the *year* format, they are specialist servers like Ubuntu Core 20, and are limited to *snap* packages only (thus cannot use `dpkg`, `apt` type of commands).  There is no specialist product release in 2021, thus no 21.  Ubuntu's main products are *year.month* in format, ie. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was the long-term-release in 2020-April; Ubuntu 21.04 (2021-April) a short-term product that users upgraded to the next product 21.10 (2021-October) to continue getting support as they weren't LTS or *long-term-support* releases; they are not *year* or *snap* only systems.

Comment: @marco Good question. Let's say, we ping google.com and microsoft.com every 10 second. If both of them don't respond, we switch internet connection automatically.

Comment: You could create a script which does the pings and in case of failure it changes the default gateway of your node. As I said, before you go for a "professional" solution make sure the detection algorithm fits to your needs. "link down" is something else than "ping failed".